# configuring exchnage server for hosting company

Tags: email, windows-server-2008, web-hosting, exchange-2010

my question is,

if any hosting company want to host a exchange server 2010 for its clients,
is this possible?

if yes then how we can manage Multiple Domains ?

> if above is possible with accepted domains then second option bellow look difficult

second how we deal with multiple email accounts with same id like "sales" or "info" etc?

> every one like info for log in no one like to use info1 and info2 to log in or email account to log in like info@domain1, info@domain4 etc

if this

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done - actually exchange has a specific install mode in 2010 for hosting providers. Licensing MUST BE DONE USING SPLA, or basically otherwise (whether you paid for it or not) you basically use stolen software. Reselling MS softawre access is SPLA. Point.

Now, SPLA hosting for exchange comes with full documentation. Read it.

Answer (score 0):

If a hosting company wants to offer hosted exchange services as a product offering it can be done.

I will not go into the details of the infrastructure however in short mission critical so it should be robust high performing and sustainable against failures.

In short create lots of OUs (organizational units) name each one based on the client companies name.  within that OU you can create the users who are members of that client company as well as distribution lists.  If you want one of the users to create mailboxes on their own just delegate rights to that OU.

On the exchange side create storage groups, you can start with more SGs however depending how many clients you start to put on it, it may get out of hand.  The idea behind multiple SGs is to not share the I/O resources and also improve the backup and recovery process should disaster strike.

Last but not least you will want to read up on GALs and OABs, create security groups in each OU per client and grant that group rights to that GAL/OAB and all others deny, this way they wont share resources or view their existance.

A lot of fine tuning in between, best of luck!